# Highlighting function calls in textmate

Tags: syntax-highlighting, textmate, coda

It feels like I'm missing something really simple here. I've been using Coda for a while now and I'm now playing around with Textmate. I'm unable to find a way to syntax highlight function calls in Textmate. I've poked around the documentation but can't believe I'd have to dig deep into Textmate and mess around with regex to make this work.

This is in textmate:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uSmz.png

Function calls are inheriting the foreground color. This is javascript but I get the same in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Textmate, syntax coloring is entirely controlled by the language definition in the "bundle" of the relevant language.  Both the PHP (HTML) and Javascript bundles give function **definitions** special treatment, but neither highlights function **calls**.

So yes, if you want to change this, you'll need to use the Bundle Editor and learn to edit the regex-based language definition (marked with an L icon in the bundle).